# use of regex for matching the parenthesis ordering and conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to apply the regular expressions to find and replace the unwanted parenthesis and operators in the input string.

Here is the possible input for me: 4 types from a through d. [Invalid Inputs]

```
a). 1 and (2 or 3) ()
b). ( and 2)
c). (or 4)
d). ()
```

all these 4 are invalid cases , the valid ones should be as [Valid Inputs]

```
a). 1 and 2
b). (1 and 2)
c). 1 and (2 or 4)
```

Based on this requirement, i have written the regex, but i have written in 2 parts and need help in joining them to a single regex.

```
a). ([(]+[\s]*[)]+) -> to find the empty parenthesis
b). (([(]+[\s]*[and|or]+[\s]*)) -> to find cases like b or c in invalid inputs.
```

Kindly suggest a way to combine the above. further i want to do removal of the invalid parts in the inputs, which i can do in javascript like string.replace(regex).

Kindly analyze and give comments on this process.

Comment: It's not clear, do you want only to validate input, or you want to heuristically clear it from errors. From my point of view, the second approach won't work.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood square brackets '[' and ']'. For example [and|or] means any one of the six characters 'a', 'n', 'd', '|', 'o', 'r'.

Comment: This kind of problem is not suitable for regexp's. What you have is basically a recursive grammar, and regexp's can't handle them. Because it is limited in its recursion, only allowing a single level of embedding, it is _possible_ in regexp, but the solution will probably be complicated and unclear.

Comment: @ColinFine: More specifically, it's unsuitable for JavaScript regexes. Modern regex engines like those in .NET, PHP or Perl do support recursion.

Comment: To be more constructive: Can you constrain your problem? For example, can you guarantee that you'll never encounter nested parentheses? Or at least guarantee an upper limit for nesting?

Comment: @ColinFine: Thanks for your clarification. Given your suggestion, i hope i can refine the input using stack and recursive function in javascript itself. I will try it out and update here.

Comment: @ColinFine: Anyways, i am currently working on the solution using recursive validation itself, as i am using associative arrays.

Comment: @ColinFine : Is it possible for me to validate using any expression tree or other ways in C# at server side. Kindly let me know that procedure also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\((\s*|\s*(?:and|or)\s*\d+\s*|\s*\d+\s*(?:and|or)\s*|\s*(?:and|or)\s*)\)/
```

is a Regex that checks for the content of a bracket pair: either empty, missing operand on the left, missing operand on the right or no operands at all.

But watch out! This neither checks for validity of un-bracketed expressions, nor is it rekursive, as Colin Fine already mentioned. If you liked to check for that, I'd propose to replace from inside up:

```
var s = string;
var oneoperator = /^\s*\d+\s*(and|or)\s*\d+\s*$/;
while (true) {
    s = s.replace(/\(([^)])\)/, function(all, inner) {
        if (inner.match(oneoperator)
            return "0"; // or any other valid operand
        else
            throw new SyntaxError("Math Syntax mismatch");
    });
    if (s.match(oneoperator))
        break; // return true
}
// to be improved
```